# Initialize a collection of byte* in C#

Tags: c#, unsafe

My unsafe method accepts a collection `byte[]`s. All of these `byte[]`s are of the same size.

I need to iterate over them all, searching for certain patterns. The search is inherently reinterpret-cast style: at each offset, I need to consider a value as if it were a float, a double, a short, an int, etc. So getting a `byte*` for each input `byte[]` and incrementing it on each iteration seems like a natural approach.

Unfortunately I can't find any way to create a collection of `byte*` - or, more specifically, to initialize it from a collection of arrays. Any ideas?

Here's a somewhat contrived version of the task:

```
static unsafe void SearchIteration(List<byte[]> arrays, byte[] resultArr)
{
    fixed (byte* resultFix = resultArr)
    {
        byte* resultPtr = resultFix;
        byte*[] pointers = new byte*[arrays.Count];

        <some code to fix all the arrays and store the pointers in "pointers">

        int remaining = resultArr.Length;
        while (remaining > 0)
        {
            <look at resultPtr and each of the pointers and update *resultPtr>

            remaining--;
            for (int i = 0; i < pointers.Length; i++)
                pointers[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially the question is how to initialize `pointers` with the addresses of `arrays`, while pinning the arrays so that GC doesn't move them.

Comment: What exactly is your collection of objects, and what are in the byte[] ?

Comment: Do you really need to have all byte[] in arrays to be pinned at the same time, or could you process them one after another?

Comment: @Raynos sorry for confusion, I simplified a bit and forgot to remove one reference to "objects". Gone now. Just `byte[]`s.

Comment: @dtb yes, I need to compare them all to each other. For example, at a given offset, check if all offsets interpreted as floats represent the same float within a range of, say, +/- `10.0f`.

Comment: BitConverter is too slow for your purpose? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle.aspx

Comment: To me, it seems dealing with pointers and such in C# shouldn't be necessary and you might be able to abstract it to a higher level. What exactly are the byte[]'s ?

Comment: @Raynos they are copies of a given process' private memory, so not abstractable to anything higher level.

Comment: Sounds like your snooping on other processes. c# just doesnt sound like the language of choice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `GCHandle.Alloc()` from `System.Runtime.InteropServices`:

```
var handles = new GCHandle[arrays.Count];
byte*[] pointers = new byte*[arrays.Count];
for(int i = 0; i < arrays.Count; ++i)
{
    handles[i] = GCHandle.Alloc(arrays[i], GCHandleType.Pinned);
    pointers[i] = (byte*)handles[i].AddrOfPinnedObject();
}
try
{
    /* process pointers */
}
finally
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arrays.Count; ++i)
    {
        handles[i].Free();
    }
}
```

Comment: That pins the objects. But where does the pointer point to (the array content or the CLR object header of the array object)?

Comment: it points to exatly what you are expecting - first array element